# Convergence Conjecture: True or False?

Tags: real-analysis

The conjecture is:

If $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$ and $|b_n-b|\leq a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $(b_n)\rightarrow b$.

I believe it is true. Here is my justification.
Suppose $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$. Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that we have $-\epsilon<a_n<\epsilon$ when $n\geq N$. So, when $n\geq N$, $|b_n-b|\leq a_n$, implies $|b_n-b|\leq a_n<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. So, $(b_n) \rightarrow b$.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: This is basically the $\epsilon$ formulation for the concept of a limit..

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is true and your proof is correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your conjecture: Let $(a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $(b_n)\rightarrow 0$ for any sequence $(c_n)$ and real $c$ we have
$$a_n\leq c_n-c \leq b_n$$
then $(c_n)\rightarrow c$.